# How to StopIteration

Tags: python, iteration, pygame

I this code using iteration and I keep getting an error. Not sure why it is going what it is doing. I am new to this type of programming and using this in a game I created. I'm also not familiar with this website, so please bear with me. This code is to be showing an explosion. As it steps through the images of the explosion everything is fine, until it gets to the end, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Project April\Alien Metor Storm v1_4\AlienMetorStorm.py", line 560, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Project April\Alien Metor Storm v1_4\AlienMetorStorm.py", line 222, in main
    ships.update()
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 399, in update
    for s in self.sprites(): s.update(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Project April\Alien Metor Storm v1_4\explosion.py", line 26, in update
    self.image = next(self.image_iter)
StopIteration
```

Here is the code:

```
import pygame

class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,color,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.frame = 0
        self.width = 0
        self.height = 0
        self.x_change = 0
        self.y_change = 0
        self.images = []
        for i in range (0,25):
            img = pygame.image.load('Explosion'+str(i)+'.png').convert()
            img.set_colorkey([0,0,0])
            self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.image_iter = iter(self.images)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = x
        self.rect.top = y

    def update(self):
        self.image = next(self.image_iter)
```

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

`StopIteration` is the exception raised when an iterator is exhausted.  you can catch it like any other exception:

```
def update(self):
     try:
         self.image = next(self.image_iter)
     except StopIteration:
         pass #move on, explosion is over ...
```

Alternatively, the `next` builtin allows you to return something special when the iterable is exhausted by passing a second argument:

```
def update(self):
    self.image = next(self.image_iter,None)
    if self.image is None:
        pass #move on, explosion is over ...
```

Comment: And if the animation should repeat forever, [`itertools.cycle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) will do that.

Comment: didn't know about the second argument to `next()`, plus one!

Comment: @TokenMacGuy -- another one that is almost never used is the 2 argument form of `iter` (which is really different than the 1 argument form)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want `update` to do, but here is a generator version you could use so you don't need an external iter

```
def update(self):
    for image in self.images:
        self.image = image
        yield
```

or if you want to iterate forever

```
def update(self):
    while True:
        for image in self.images:
            self.image = image
            yield
```